# Identify Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

How can we know that a site is a Sharepoint Site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because its bloated and slow?   Just kidding.

If you mean as a user, you can do a view source and there are several indicators, such as

`<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />`

Comment: ZING! +1 for "Because its bloated and slow?"

Comment: Thanks!. Also in source found references to default Core.js and Core.css, etc. So its good enough.

Answer (score 3):

I will try these to check if a site is a Sharepoint site

1) Check Url, if it has /sites/ in the url

2) check if accessing [ServerName]/_layouts/images/ERROR.GIF gives a Image

3) check if accessing [ServerName]/_vti_bin/sites.asmx?wsdl will display wsdl for the webservice

4) check if source has
<
meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" 
>

5) check if source show usage of init.js, core.js

6) check if _spBodyOnLoadWrapper function is being called on page load.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to request URL /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll.  If you get back a response other than 404 then you know it is a SharePoint site.

I explain some more details [in this blog post](http://sharepoint.nailhead.net/2010/01/internet-explorer-discussion-toolbar.html).